# Running CTC loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I wanted to try CTC loss function on Shakespeare dataset and during calculating the loss, the predicted tensor shape is (64, 100, 65) which does not match the label shape of (64, 100. So I used some maths to convert the dimensions but with an error.

**Code**

```
def loss(labels, logits):
  return tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits)

example_batch_loss  = loss(labels=target_example_batch, logits=tf.math.argmax(tf.convert_to_tensor(example_batch_predictions), axis=-1, output_type=tf.int64))
```

**Error**

> cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int64 tensor but is a double tensor [Op:Mul]

Please help me find a solution to use CTC loss.

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding the argmax of the model output, i.e., the indices where the output has the highest value. CTC loss (just as most loss functions) works with logits, the unnormalized probability distribution produced by the model. Therefore, there is nothing wrong with having a prediction of shape (64, 100, 65) and the target only (64, 100).

Note, however, that CTC is designed to handle cases when you have much longer model output than the target. The typical use case is speech recognition where you have plenty of signal windows matching to relatively few phonemes. If your output length and target length are the same, CTC degenerates to the standard cross-entropy.

Assuming `example_batch_predictions` is your model output before normalizing it by softmax, then you should do:

```py
example_batch_loss  = loss(labels=target_example_batch, logits=example_batch_predictions, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int64))
```